# Define custom driver for node-orm2

Tags: database-connection, node-orm2

I'm using Firebase as a persistence layer and also wanted to use node-orm2 for data modeling. I'm trying to find a documentation for creating custom driver but it seems like it has not been documented yet.

Anyone has experience in implementing custom driver before? How complicated is it to implement it? A tutorial would be helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is documented in the repository directly, rather than the wiki, but there's a link to the guide at the bottom of the Readme:

https://github.com/dresende/node-orm2/blob/master/Adapters.md

Though it's not exactly very detailed, it's a good start to know where to look for details.